# Items inside GridView getting repeated when screen scrolls

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, drawable

I'm using a GridView to show a set of Categories that user can chose. Each item of the grid is consisted by an ImageView and a TextView, both retrieved from server. When an item is touched, another activity is started.

I thought everything was going right, until I've noticed that some itens were getting repeated when I scrolls the screen. Whenever I scroll down trough the grid, and then back, itens change itś position and get duplicated. But even when I touch the messed up itens, the right values are send to the next activity.

Looking in LogCat, any repeated request to server occurs. In fact, I've got this while scrolling:

```
06-28 12:36:38.554: D/dalvikvm(358): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2061 objects / 156024 bytes in 51ms
06-28 12:36:42.915: D/dalvikvm(358): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6590 objects / 737528 bytes in 57ms
06-28 12:38:26.725: D/dalvikvm(358): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 5426 objects / 468176 bytes in 71ms
06-28 12:38:26.875: D/dalvikvm(358): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 409 objects / 17480 bytes in 68ms
```

Looks like everytime I scroll, itens get redraw...

UPDATE: It only redraw itens on the first time I scroll down the GridView. After this, all itens, including repeated ones, keeps on its places.

My java class:

```
public void proccess(){
    int qtdCategorias = json.length();
    imagens = new Drawable[qtdCategorias];
    categorias = new String[qtdCategorias];
    for (int i=0; i<qtdCategorias; i++){
        JSONArray c = json.optJSONArray(i);
        String urlAmigavel = null;
        String imagemSite = null;
        String nomeCategoria = null;
        try {
            urlAmigavel = c.getString(6);
            imagemSite = c.getString(3);
            nomeCategoria = c.getString(2);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("CategoriasJogarActivity", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        categorias[i] = nomeCategoria;
        imagens[i] = getImagem(urlAmigavel, imagemSite);
    }


    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.include3);

    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ctx, imagens, categorias);

    gridview.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            String name = null;
            String idt = null;
            try {
                JSONArray c = json.optJSONArray(position);
                name = c.getString(2);
                idt = c.getString(0);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("CategoriasJogarActivity",
                        "JSONException" + e.toString());
            }

            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    JogarActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_ID, idt);
            in.putExtra(TAG_PRIMEIRAPERGUNTA, true);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
}


public Drawable getImagem(String urlAmigavel, String img) {
    String url = "http://www.qranio.com/pergunta/" + urlAmigavel + "/"+ img;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        URL urlImagem = new URL(url);
        is = (InputStream) getObjeto(urlImagem);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        Log.e("CategoriasJogarActivity", e1.toString());
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");

    return d;
}

private Object getObjeto(URL url) {
    Object content = null;
    try {
        content = url.getContent();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("CategoriasJogarActivity", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return content;
}
```

imageAdapter class

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context mContext;
private final Drawable[] mThumbIds;
private final String[] mTextIds;


public ImageAdapter(Context c, Drawable[] d, String[] s) {
    mContext = c;
    mThumbIds = d;
    mTextIds = s;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

//create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //ImageView imageView;
    View v;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(     Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item_layout, null);
        TextView text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);
        text.setText(mTextIds[position]);
        ImageView image = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
        image.setImageDrawable(mThumbIds[position]);


    } else {

        v = (View) convertView;
    }


    return v;
}


}
```

gridview_item_layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridview_item_layout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

<ImageView android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:minHeight="100dip"
android:minWidth="100dip"
>
</ImageView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/grid_item_text"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:text="TextView"
android:gravity="center"
android:textColor="#F9A512"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="18dp"
>
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

gridview xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="10dip"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dip"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:padding="5dip"
/>
```

I saw other questions about this same issue, but none of them answered. Any ideas of what's happening?

Comment: Use ViewHolder is good practice of code

Answer (score 84, accepted):

It's normal that you see the same items as you scroll down the `GridView` because in the `getView` method you set the drawables for the `ImageView` only when the `convertView` is `null`(for example for the first elements that are seen when the `GridView` appear on the screen). If the `convertView` is not `null`, meaning you have a recycled row view, you don't set the correct image and you remain with the image that was previously set on this  recycled view. Try to modify the `getView` method like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(     Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item_layout, parent, false);
    } else {
        v = (View) convertView;
    }
    TextView text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);
    text.setText(mTextIds[position]);
    ImageView image = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
    image.setImageDrawable(mThumbIds[position]);
    return v;
}
```

Clicking an element shows you the correct items because you use the `position` parameter to retrieve the data.

Comment: That worked! Although LogCat keeps displaying those GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC lines when I first scroll down the grid...

Comment: @LucasJota That is the garbage collector, I think it's normal(if it doesn't make the `GridView` laggy). Keep in mind that you're querying for those images and also keeping them in memory(I don't know how many you have).

Comment: Worked perfectly for me with Button + Textview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401630/gridview-images-are-changing-postion-when-scrolling

Comment: If you add the `TextView` programmatically. The solution is a little bit different. For example; (Assuming you have a LinearLayout)

`LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.NAME_OF_YOUR_LINEARLAYOUT);
linearLayout.removeAllViews();
TextView textViewDay = new TextView(mContext);
textViewDay.setText("YOURTEXT");
linearLayout.addView(textViewDay);`

Therefore, `linearLayout.removeAllViews();` would be needed so that you do not end up adding more TextViews on each call to `getView(...)`, which is called every time you scroll up or down

Comment: Even though I am doing the same, I don't understand why it's not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @NamrataBagerwal Please post a new question and provide the code you currently use to get help with the problem you have.

Answer (score 2):

These is my code for GirdView with Button + Textview

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);  
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        TextView text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.texto_grid);
        text.setText(app_listaActiva_NOMBRES[position]);
        Button image = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.miniatura_grid);
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_button);
        image.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener2(position,app_listaActiva_SONIDOS));
        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change here and try it again,

```
   View v;
if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(     Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item_layout, null);
    TextView text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);
    text.setText(mTextIds[position]);


} else {

    v = (View) convertView;
}
if(view!=null)
        {
               ImageView image = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
               image.setImageDrawable(mThumbIds[position]);
               notifyDataSetChanged();  //Calling this helped to solve the problem. 
        }


return v;
}
```

Comment: Why would you add an extra check, while we we already checked for convertview==null, i would put the last block in else block.

Comment: yeah you are right, but it didn't work in the "else statement" for me some how, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

**Send and gridview or listview and In constructor implement this method
implement onscroll listener**

```
    this.mGridView = mGridView;
    this.mGridView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            Log.v("onScrollStateChanged", "onScrollStateChanged");
            if (scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                isScrollStop = true;

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                isScrollStop = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            Log.v("onScroll", "onScroll");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ViewHolder` static class fixed repeating items for me.

Also changing `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `fill_parent` didn't help.

I went through this tutorial
http://android-vogue.blogspot.com/2011/06/custom-gridview-in-android-with.html